# EF is not creating a column for a foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

In my domain model, which is of a moderate size - about 20 generated tables - there is only one relationship that Entity Framework is not mapping and I can't work out why. It is the relationship (1-1) between an `AccountRecord` and an `Account`. An `Account` refers to an Account which has users.

The classes look like this:

```
public class Account
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    /* snip */
    AccountRecord Record { get; set; }
}

public class AccountRecord
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    Account Account { get; set; }
    /* snip */
}
```

The mappings are defined as follows:

```
    public AccountConfiguration()
    {
        // Table name and primary key
        ToTable("Accounts");
        HasKey(x => x.ID);
        Property(x => x.ID)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
            .HasColumnName("AccountId");

        HasOptional(x => x.AccountRecord).WithRequired(x => x.Account);
    }

    public AccountRecordConfiguration()
    {
        // Table name and primary key
        ToTable("AccountRecords");
        HasKey(x => x.ID);
        Property(x => x.ID)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
            .HasColumnName("AccountRecordId");

        HasRequired(x => x.Account).WithOptional(x => x.AccountRecord);
    }
```

All of the other columns for both entities are being created, just not this one. When I try to set an account record for an account, I get the following: `A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column`

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out, thought I'd put the answer up if anyone finds this Googling.

EF was not creating the column and instead was putting the foreign key on AccountRecordId to the Accounts table as there is a 1-1 relationship. The solution was to remove the `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` from the Account Record PK.

Comment: OP has already done this here`.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
            .HasColumnName("AccountRecordId");`